# Challenging CSS: Changing Element based on sibling location

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm stuck on how to approach this. In the background is an animated blob. When the blob moves behind the ampersand element, I'd like it (the ampersand element) to change color so it can be seen. When the blob moves away, I'd like the color to change back. I've looked into using something like this:

https://css-tricks.com/switch-font-color-for-different-backgrounds-with-css/

But I can't manipulate it into sensing if an element is BEHIND it in order to change color. Is there a way to do this in CSS or vanilla JS? I'm really stuck.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum<br>sed do eiusmod<br><span class="ampersand">&</span>Excepteur</h1>
    <div class="shape-blob"></div>
    <div class="shape-blob one"></div>
    <div class="shape-blob two"></div>
</div>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,900');

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    background: #1D8A99;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.shape-blob {
    background:#F28123;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 30% 50% 20% 40%;
    animation: 
        transform 20s ease-in-out infinite both alternate,
        movement_one 40s ease-in-out infinite both;
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%;
    top: 50%;
}
.shape-blob.one{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    left: -200px;
    top: -150px;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    animation: transform 30s ease-in-out infinite both alternate, movement_two 60s ease-in-out infinite both;
}

.shape-blob.two{
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    left: 500px;
    top: -150px;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    animation: transform 30s ease-in-out infinite both alternate, movement_two 60s ease-in-out infinite both;
}

@keyframes transform
{
    0%,
  100% { border-radius: 33% 67% 70% 30% / 30% 30% 70% 70%; } 
   20% { border-radius: 37% 63% 51% 49% / 37% 65% 35% 63%; } 
   40% { border-radius: 36% 64% 64% 36% / 64% 48% 52% 36%; } 
   60% { border-radius: 37% 63% 51% 49% / 30% 30% 70% 70%; } 
   80% { border-radius: 40% 60% 42% 58% / 41% 51% 49% 59%; } 
}


@keyframes movement_one
{
    0%,
  100% { transform: none; }
   50% { transform: translate(50%, 20%) rotateY(10deg) scale(1.2); }
}

@keyframes movement_two
{
    0%,
  500% { transform: none; }
   50% { transform: translate(50%, 20%) rotate(-200deg) scale(1.2);}
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 5em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    line-height: .9em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.ampersand{
    color:#F28123;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a certain amount using mix-blend-mode but the HTML structure needs to change as mix-blend-mode doesn't work on siblings. We also have to be careful about stacking contexts.

Moving the header text to after the blobs, setting it within a span rather than an h1 element and making the ampersand a complementary sort of color and mix-blend-mode set at difference, the ampersand will change color as the blob passes under it.

Playing with the colors and positioning may give a better result, but this hopefully will get things started:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,900');

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    background: #1D8A99;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;    color:#F28123;

}

.shape-blob {
    background:#F28123;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 30% 50% 20% 40%;
    animation: 
        transform 20s ease-in-out infinite both alternate,
        movement_one 40s ease-in-out infinite both;
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%;
    top: 50%;
}
.shape-blob.one{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    left: -200px;
    top: -150px;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    animation: transform 30s ease-in-out infinite both alternate, movement_two 60s ease-in-out infinite both;
}

.shape-blob.two{
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    left: 500px;
    top: -150px;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    animation: transform 30s ease-in-out infinite both alternate, movement_two 60s ease-in-out infinite both;
}

@keyframes transform
{
    0%,
  100% { border-radius: 33% 67% 70% 30% / 30% 30% 70% 70%; } 
   20% { border-radius: 37% 63% 51% 49% / 37% 65% 35% 63%; } 
   40% { border-radius: 36% 64% 64% 36% / 64% 48% 52% 36%; } 
   60% { border-radius: 37% 63% 51% 49% / 30% 30% 70% 70%; } 
   80% { border-radius: 40% 60% 42% 58% / 41% 51% 49% 59%; } 
}


@keyframes movement_one
{
    0%,
  100% { transform: none; }
   50% { transform: translate(50%, 20%) rotateY(10deg) scale(1.2); }
}

@keyframes movement_two
{
    0%,
  500% { transform: none; }
   50% { transform: translate(50%, 20%) rotate(-200deg) scale(1.2);}
}

span.overlay {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 5em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    line-height: .9em;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.ampersand {
    color: #ff0876;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="shape-blob"></div>
    <div class="shape-blob one"></div>
    <div class="shape-blob two"></div>
    <span class="overlay">
      Lorem ipsum<br>sed do eiusmod<br>
      <span class="ampersand">&amp;</span>
      Excepteur
    </span>
</div>>
```